# plyr.js add live button same as YouTube live stream [skip ahead live broadcast]

Tags: javascript, video-streaming, plyr, youtube-livestreaming-api, plyr.js

I am using plyr.js, using this player iframe I am loading a youtube live stream video.
I need to show the Live button on the player.

if a user is not watching the current live minutes, show this button and click it go current live stream point. same as in youtube player Live button.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

I have been trying to find a solution for this as well and after asking ChatGPT for help and nothing it gave me really worked I played with a lot of different options and here is what I came up with that I think is working for me:

```
function resumeVideos() {
    player2.playVideo();
    var currentTime = player1.getCurrentTime();
    var targetTime = currentTime + 6000000;
    player1.seekTo(targetTime, true);
    player1.playVideo();
```

I tried many other things before this but this is what has been working consistently. I add the 6 million seconds (~1,700 hours) because when I look at the output of getCurrentTime anywhere on the seek bar (which seems to only go back ~12 hours) of this live video it is over 43 million seconds or ~12,120 hours (which must be the uptime of the stream?) so I add 6mil seconds to whatever the current time is and it should always be more than enough which takes you to the current live point.
(video I've been testing with: https://www.youtube.com/embed/jfKfPfyJRdk)

hope this works for you or at least helps you get in the right direction.

(edit: pasted the wrong code, sorry)